# Tridion 2013SP1: File upload problems using latest chrome on PC

Tags: 2013, cme

A number of our CMS users are experiencing problems uploading PDFs and images to Tridion using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m on Windows 7. Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds or fixes for this?

Other browsers and Mac Chrome are working fine. Looking at the requests trace, it seems like the form fails to submit/post on PC chrome. We are in the process of submitting a support ticket with SDL but curious to know why no one else is seeing this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had file upload problems with Chrome 34, didn't try with Chrome 35 yet - it was fixed by applying hotfix CME_2013.1.0.87586 (available from SDL Tridion World)

Comment: To see the hotfix in Tridion World, you will need to be logged in.  Navigate to Downloads, Hotfixes and select the version of Tridion applicable, in this case SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm you that even on Chrome 35 this issue is coming up. This issue is there (along with many others) after Chrome version 33 onwards. You can apply the hot-fix suggested by Nuno or downgrade to a earlier version of Chrome or just discard the chrome and use some other browser as the above hotfix may fix this issue but there are few other which it might not:

1. Videos put in html using embed tag will not be played in version 34
2. Changing Template Icons shown during Inline Editing might not work with Chrome 34+